# how does More_like_this elasticsearch work (into the whole index)

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, lucene, comparison, morelikethis

So first we are getting a list of termVectors, which contain all tokens, then we create a `map<token, frequency in the document>.`
then the method createQueue will determine a score by deleting, stopWords and word which occurs not enough, compute idf, then idf * doc_frequency of a given token which is equals to its token, then we keeping the 25 best one, but after that how does it work? How is it compare to the whole index? I read http://cephas.net/blog/2008/03/30/how-morelikethis-works-in-lucene/ but that didn't explain it, or I miss the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a `TermQuery` out of each of those terms, and chucks them all into a simple `BooleanQuery`, boosting each term by the previously calculated tfidf score (`boostFactor * myScore / bestScore`, where boostFactor can be set by the user).

Here is [the source (version 5.0)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-queries/5.0.0/org/apache/lucene/queries/mlt/MoreLikeThis.java#MoreLikeThis.createQuery%28org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue%29):

```
private Query createQuery(PriorityQueue<ScoreTerm> q) {
  BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
  ScoreTerm scoreTerm;
  float bestScore = -1;

  while ((scoreTerm = q.pop()) != null) {
    TermQuery tq = new TermQuery(new Term(scoreTerm.topField, scoreTerm.word));

    if (boost) {
      if (bestScore == -1) {
        bestScore = (scoreTerm.score);
      }
      float myScore = (scoreTerm.score);
      tq.setBoost(boostFactor * myScore / bestScore);
    }

    try {
      query.add(tq, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    }
    catch (BooleanQuery.TooManyClauses ignore) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return query;
}
```